# How to know an ip address has viewed all the links?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose, I have 200 links and if the visitors visits continuously all the links then I want to offer a free pdf book
after last link but if someone directly visits last link then offer should not display.

In this case the user may visit the site per month or any long time to complete the tutorial site (this site) and the
user may delete the cookies so I should not use local storage or something like that.

So, I'm pulling an option with the users' ip address and if that ip's users completes the whole page visit the offer should be displayed.

So, how to decide if an ip address has viewed all the pages and if the user is at last link then display offer.

Comment: it is a server side activity, in client side there is very little you can do... also you will have problem if the users are working within a subnet in that case you will get only their share public IP

Comment: Do you have any kind of back-end development and database?

Comment: get the ip address then save the visited link to database (could be html5 database)

Comment: IP address can also vary(some ISP do not provide static IP). Your best bet to track a user is to have a DB in your server and asking users to register before browsing your site. Now when a user Clicks on links keep incrementing the visited links count if its unique. You can keep your site open also and say that by registering you will have the opportunity to get goodies(free books etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Does it have a login feature? If so I would track page views by url and userId.
The shortcoming of ip address is that different people using the same computer will count towards the same tracking. Also, you will not get credit if you visit the site from two different locations.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to track the information with only the ip address. The IP address can change everytime the user reconnects to the internet e.g. reboot router. You will have to provide user login feature so you can associate the link visits with that user account.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be as follows using some server-side storage:

1. When a browser hits your server on any of the pages you are tracking, you see if there's already a tracking cookie in the browser.  If not, you coin a unique ID for this browser and put it in a cookie that you set into that browser.  Make sure the path allows visibility of the cookie anywhere on the site and set the expiration for however long you want.
2. In your server-side database, create an entry for this cookie ID and record that the page that was just hit has now been seen by this cookie ID.
3. On any subsequent page hit, get the cookie ID, look it up in the database, record that this page has now been viewed by that ID and check if all the required pages have now been viewed by that ID.  If so, add the special offer to the delivery of the current page.

Using a cookied ID like this avoids issues with multiple browsers sharing a single IP address (which even happens on home networks and happens all the time on corporate networks).

If your site has a user login, it's even better to use the login ID as the user identifier because that allows you to accumulate the browsing history of the user even if they use multiple browsers/multiple computers as long as they login first.

FYI, some of the logic above can also be implemented via ajax calls made from the client upon each page load rather than work done at the time of serving the page - though this adds an extra server request for each page.